# Working with wxWidgets and Unicode

Tags: unicode, wxwidgets

I want my wxWidgets program to use unicode, I'm not sure I'm doing it right.

I have wxTextCtrl, user enters a text and the text saved to wxString variable, then being inserted to sqlite3 db, When I insert it I use `ToUTF8();`, Then when I want to show it back in the wxTextCtrl I query it from the database then use `wxString::FromUTF8(var_from_db);`
I'm not sure this is the best and most efficient way to work with unicode and wxWidgets, Am I doing it right? Is there a better way of doing that?
Thanks.

Comment: wxWidgets 3.0.2 ,Cross platform preferred or Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite has APIs working with both UTF-16 and UTF-8, but the latter is preferred so I'd say that you are doing the right thing.

But to be sure about it you should really have unit tests verifying that saving strings in the database and reading them back returns the same thing. Then you won't have to wonder whether it works or not, but you will really know it.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know what you mean by "doing it right".

The main thing is: does it work?

Assuming it is working correctly, then you will have to decide why you care whether it is using UTF16 or UTF8.  Do you care about performance?  Communicating over the internet?